# Method to calculate the de Rham cohomology of $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, differential-forms, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to follow through a method to calculate the de Rham cohomology groups of $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n$ from the de Rham cohomology groups of $S^n$.

I'm trying to show that differential k-forms on $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n$ are in 1-1 correspondence with differential k-forms, $\alpha$ on $S^n$ that satisfy $\sigma^* \alpha = \alpha$, where $\sigma$ is the antipodal map. I've started trying to show this for the case where $\alpha$ is a 1-form as an example but I am having difficulty even there.

If we let $\pi: S^n \to \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n$ be the map $x \to [x]$ (i.e. sends points on sphere to line through origin) then as this map is surjective, the derivative maps $T_x\pi$ and $T_{\sigma(x)}\pi$ are also surjective and are therefore isomorphisms. (I'm not sure that map is surjective implies derivative surjective so would be interested to see an argument here as well!). Now given a 1-form $\alpha$ with $\sigma^* \alpha = \alpha$ we can define a form on $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n$ by:

$$\beta([x]) = ((T_x\pi)^{-1})^* \alpha(x)$$

Now I'd like to show this is well-defined by showing that $\beta([x]) = \beta([-x])$. We see that $\beta([-x]) = ((T_{\sigma(x)}\pi)^{-1})^* \alpha(-x)$ but now I'm struggling to equate this to $\beta([x])$. Is it true that $\alpha(-x) = \sigma^* \alpha(x)$ and given that how do we make a relation between $((T_{\sigma(x)}\pi)^{-1})^* \sigma^*$ and $((T_x\pi)^{-1})^*$? It's also not clear to me how we can show this correspondence is 1-1?

Once I have sorted this issue I would like to then find the cohomology groups. We can define a projection the k-forms on $S^n$ by $\beta \to \frac{\beta + \sigma^*\beta}{2}$ and I believe this descends to a surjective map on the cohomology groups $H^k(S^n) \to H^k(\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n)$ but then it seems the most I can say is that $H^k(\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n)$ is a sub vector space of $H^k(S^n)$.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, since $\pi = \pi\circ\sigma$, if $\beta$ is a $k$-form on $\Bbb RP^n$, then $\alpha = \pi^*\beta = (\pi\circ\sigma)^*\beta = \sigma^*(\pi^*\beta) = \sigma^*\alpha$. Conversely, we know that $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism. So, given a point $[x]\in\Bbb RP^n$, choose a neighborhood $U$ of $x\in S^n$ so that $\pi|_U\colon U\to \pi(U)$ is a diffeomorphism. Given a $k$-form $\alpha$ on $S^n$ satisfying $\alpha=\sigma^*\alpha$, on $\pi(U)$ we define the $k$-form $\beta  = \big((\pi|_U)^{-1}\big)^*\alpha$. (This is making *local* what you did *at a point* in your write-up.) Since $\pi|_{\sigma(U)} =\pi|_U\circ\sigma$, we have $(\pi|_{\sigma(U)})^{-1} = \sigma^{-1}\circ(\pi|_U)^{-1}=\sigma\circ(\pi|U)^{-1}$ and so it follows that $$ \big((\pi|_{\sigma(U)})^{-1}\big)^*\alpha = 
\big(\sigma\circ(\pi|U)^{-1}\big)^*\alpha = \big((\pi|U)^{-1}\big)^*\sigma^*\alpha = \big((\pi|U)^{-1}\big)^*\alpha;$$
thus, $\beta$ is in fact well-defined.

Thus, the vector space of $k$-forms on $\Bbb RP^n$ is the vector space of $\sigma$-invariant $k$-forms on $S^n$. Moreover, this equality respects closedness and exactness. Thus, $H^k(\Bbb RP^n) \cong H^k_\sigma (S^n)$, where by the latter we mean the vector space of closed $\sigma$-invariant $k$-forms mod exact $\sigma$-invariant $k$-forms. All that remains for you to do is to decide what $H^k_\sigma (S^n)$ is. The only interesting case is $k=n$, and I'll let you work on that for a while.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it is very helpful! I can follow your argument but I'm just trying to understand a few minor points (probably very straightforward!). Why do we have to work on a local set like this rather than point wise as I did? For the $k=n$ case, if we work in some coordinate system I think we have $\sigma^*(\alpha) = (-1)^n \alpha$ so depending on the parity of $n$ we either have $H_\sigma^n(S^n) = H^n(S^n) = \mathbb{R}$ or zero?

Comment: Also to know that $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism, is that an application of the inverse function theorem? Is it true that a surjective map has a surjective derivative? (then we could apply the IFT)

Comment: To establish smoothness of $\beta$, you can't do a pointwise argument; you need a local one. Smooth covering maps are local diffeomorphisms (because you have local smooth inverses); no, surjections needn't be submersions (consider $f(x)=x^3$ in $\Bbb R$). Finally, your parity is wrong: $\sigma^*(\alpha) = (-1)^{n+1}\alpha$ for a volume form $\alpha$ on $S^n$. You can check this by writing down an explicit formula, if you like.

Comment: Okay I understand, thanks. So to show $\pi$ has surjective derivative you really need to work in local coordinates and pick a chart $U$ on $S^n$ that doesn't intersect it's antipodal points and then write down explicitly a map $\pi_{\mathrm{loc}}: U \to P^n$ and then as that map is invertible the derivative must be invertible (just by the fact that derivatives respect function composition)? And yes, oops, parity should be $\sigma^*(\alpha) = (-1)^{n}\alpha$ so for even n $H^n(\mathbb{R}P^n)$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Right, the chain rule tells you that if you have a (local) smooth inverse, then the derivative is an isomorphism. Your parity is still wrong. If you know about orientability, given a compact $n$-manifold $M$, $H^n(M) \cong R$  is equivalent to orientability (a nowhere-vanishing $n$-form gives you an orientation and vice-versa). Perhaps you know that $\Bbb RP^2$ is not orientable; this is a check on the parities. But do follow my suggestion to write down the usual volume form on $S^n$ explicitly and check.

Comment: Yes I wrote the wrong thing for the parity - that's great, thanks for your help. When you say $H^n(M)  = R$ is equivalent to orientability, doesn't orient ability only tell us that $H^n(M)$ is "at least" $\mathbb{R}$ and in fact we need more information to also know that for a compact oriented n manifold $H^n(M)$ is "at most" $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Nope, you can prove easily with Stokes's Theorem that any $n$-form is cohomologous to some multiple of (any) volume form.